# Application get stuck at SplashScreen after MvvmCross upgrade to 8.x

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I upgraded all MvvmCross libraries from 7.1.2 to 8.0.0. According to "Upgrade from 7 to 8" tutorial from mvvmcross documentation, I have implemented necessary changes (override CreateLogProvider and CreateLogFactory methods and added iocProvider as parameter to InitializeFirstChance, InitializeLastChance, InitializeNavigationService and CreateApp):

```
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
    {
        protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter() => new HistoryViewPresenter(ViewAssemblies);

        protected override void InitializeFirstChance(IMvxIoCProvider iocProvider)
        {
            base.InitializeFirstChance(iocProvider);
            //Things are done here
        }

        protected override void InitializeLastChance(IMvxIoCProvider iocProvider)
        {
            base.InitializeLastChance(iocProvider);
            //Things are done here
        }

        protected override IMvxNavigationService InitializeNavigationService(IMvxIoCProvider iocProvider)
        {
            var loader = CreateViewModelLoader(iocProvider);
            Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton<IMvxViewModelLoader>(loader);
            InitializeViewDispatcher(iocProvider);
            var dispatcher = CreateViewDispatcher();
            Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton(dispatcher);
            var navigationService = new DeepNavigationService(null, loader, dispatcher, iocProvider);
            Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton<IMvxNavigationService>(navigationService);
            return navigationService;
        }

       //Another things are done here

        protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp(IMvxIoCProvider iocProvider)
        {
            return new App();
        }

        protected override ILoggerProvider CreateLogProvider()
        {
            return new SerilogLoggerProvider();
        }

        protected override ILoggerFactory CreateLogFactory()
        {
            Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .CreateLogger();

            return new SerilogLoggerFactory();
        }
    }
```

I have also created custom app start in Core project and set this class RegisterCustomAppStart:

```
public class AppStart : MvxAppStart
    {
        public AppStart(IMvxApplication application, IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(application, navigationService) { }

        protected override Task NavigateToFirstViewModel(object hint = null)
        {
            return NavigationService.Navigate<StartupViewModel>();
        }
    }

public class App : MvxApplication
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            //Services and Singletons are registered here.
            RegisterCustomAppStart<AppStart>();
        }
    }
```

And here is the issue- when I run app, my app get stuck in SplashScreen. Did anyone face similar issue? On the previous version, everything was fine. I would be grateful for some advice how to fix that

Comment: Shouldn't `MvxAndroidSetup` have a `App` type? Like `MvxAndroidSetup<App>` ?

Comment: And the `MvxApplication` to `MvxApplication<Setup,App>` like specified [here](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/upgrading/upgrade-to-mvvmcross-80?scroll=2039)

Comment: yeah, i forgot to set that, but after adding this, application still getting stuck on SplashScreen

Comment: I am just creating a new solution and comparing it to yours, so I might be mistaken. What about using `RegisterAppStart<StartupViewModel>();` instead of the `RegisterCustomAppStart` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not work and the problem is the same. I set up breakpoint at line of code `Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton(dispatcher);` and realised that app does not stop here (line upper app stops if breakpoint is set)

Comment: So maybe you are getting an Exception on the `CreateViewDispatcher` ? Put some Try/Catch to check if that works

Comment: You are right- I followed your advice and now I see I received `Failed to resolve type MvvmCross.Views.IMvxViewDispatcher`

Comment: I resolved this issue- I changed line `var dispatcher = CreateViewDispatcher();` for `var dispatcher = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxViewDispatcher>();` and it works. @JuanSturla thank you so much for help!

Comment: You are welcome! As you are the one who solved it, please write down your answer and mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue - I changed line:

`var dispatcher = CreateViewDispatcher();`

For:

`var dispatcher = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxViewDispatcher>();`

And it works.

Comment: This works for me, however I'm getting a null reference exception when calling NavigationService.Navigate<ViewModel>();